# An App for Crypto Currency Tax Declaration

Tags: taxes

For my tax declaration, I would like to use an app that allows me to scan all my transaction.
Do you know one ? Or are you interested to use one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could have been a question that could be ignored easily until last year. But after the case of IRS and Coinbase, after so many people getting tax notice from Coinbase that their information could be shared after meeting certain threshold - it's a topic and question that can't be ignored.

I had faced a similar problem of calculating my tax liability on cryptocurrency trades done on various exchanges. A couple of prominent software either ran into negative balances or they were too pricey for the profits I made.

This helped me to build one and launch it to the public. We've called it ***[BearTax - a comprehensive suite for cryptocurrency traders and accounting professionals](https://bear.tax)***. You can connect with unlimited exchanges and can process unlimited transactions without any payment needed. You can consolidate, review and calculate gain loss for free.

Processing power needs some fuel and we charge only those who would like to download tax forms and auditable CSV files. Give it a try and let me know your feedback. Appreciate the response from the whole community here